# Snow Leopard: Wake on mouse movement not working

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

Is this a feature of Snow Leopard?  Hitting a key works just as well but I'm curious if I can re-enable the mouse movement to "wake up."

**Edit**:  I'm using the Bluetooth Apple mouse.

Comment: what type of mouse are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just move the mouse. You must do a click to wake your Mac up.

Comment: Only works for wired mice methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse movement doesn't wake the computer up for me, but clicking the mouse will.

I'm using a Razer Deathadder.